# Rails Mailer: change file when delivery_method :file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, actionmailer

I want to have the file named Timestamp + normal_mail_name + ".eml"..

I looked into the rails source code, the mail-gem source code and the letter opener-gem.. Could you give me a hint how to (monkey-patch) the rails mailer to support that i can specify something like:

config.action_mailer.file_settings = { :location => Rails.root.join('tmp', 'mail'), :file_name => Time.now.to_i.to_s + "mail.eml" }

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
It would be also nice to have this mails automatically opened with my local associated email programm with launchy, like the letter opener gem.. i would do it myself, but i dont understand the sourcecodes..

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a lot of mailer stuff and you´ll want to debug the mail body, texts, etc.? Am I right?
If I am right, I would not send the mails with delivery_method :file, I just would create a real email (for example gmail) account and send the mails over a test account.

For example in your config/environments/development.rb:

```
email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/mail.yml"))[Rails.env] rescue nil

if email_settings.nil?
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
else
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "#{email_settings["address"]}",
    :port                 => email_settings["port"],
    :authentication       => "#{email_settings["authentication"]}",
    :user_name            => "#{email_settings["user_name"]}",
    :password             => "#{email_settings["password"]}",
    :enable_starttls_auto => email_settings["enable_starttls_auto"]
  }
end
```

And your mail.yml file:

```
development:
  address: smtp.gmail.com
  port: 587
  authentication: login
  user_name: test@your-domain.com
  password: yourpassword
  enable_starttls_auto: true
```

This is not really a direct answer for your question, but maybe this work around is a good choice for you. You could also configure your other environments the same way, dependent on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want skip the transmission of the emails through a real mail server to view your emails locally, two good solutions I've used are:

- https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener
- https://github.com/37signals/mail_view

A non-free, OSX-specific solution is to use http://mocksmtpapp.com/

If you want to have a copy of the raw email (headers and all), one way I would do it would be write an email interceptor and write the contents of the mail object to disk.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Something like this for `lib/development_mail_interceptor`:

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.perform_deliveries = false
    File.open("#{Time.now.to_i}-email.eml", "w") { |f| f.write(message.to_s) }
  end
end
```

and in config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

`Mail.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?`